# Failed prop type warning in unloaded component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-proptypes

I'm getting a warning for a page that I'm not currently on(being on the https://example.com/this-page).

`` Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `query` is marked as required in `OtherPage`, but its value is `undefined`. ``

"prop-types": "^15.7",
"react": "^17.0",
"react-redux": "^7.2",
"react-router-dom": "^6.0",

This component is used directly in the Route component

```
let global_props = {...}
...
<Routes>
    <Route path="/this-page" exact element={<ThisPage ...{global_props}/>}/>
    <Route path="/other-page" exact element={<OtherPage ...{global_props}/>}/>
</Routes>
```

Here's the component. Note, it's not using redux at the moment.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class OtherPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>HI</div>;
    }
}

OtherPage.propTypes = {
    query: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default OtherPage;
```

What would be the reason for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If that's literally what your routes look like, then you're getting the warning for exactly the reason it says - you're not defining the `query` property on the `<OtherPage />` element.

It doesn't matter if that route is active or not, as far as React is concerned, you're violating the contract that you set, which states that the `query` property is required. If you're not going to pass the `query` property, why not make it optional?

Aside - also, the `exact` property no longer exists on the `Route` component - via: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#relative-routes-and-links

> - <Route exact> is gone. Instead, routes with descendant routes (defined in other components) use a trailing * in their path to indicate they match deeply

---

#### Edit after question update

It's still the same problem - you've said that the query property on  `<OtherPage />` is required, but you're not guaranteeing that you'll supply the `query` property to `<OtherPage />`. If `global_props` definitely has a `query` property, then you won't get the error:

```
const global_props = {
    query: {},
};

// No errors!
return <OtherPage {...global_props} />;
```

It seems odd that you're marking the property as required if you're not always going to pass the property (which is literally what the error is saying ). Your only choices here are to either make the property optional and then deal with `undefined` in the `<OtherPage />` control, or provide a `defaultProps.query` to cater for it not being passed:

```
const OtherPage = ({ query }) => {
  // ...
};

OtherPage.defaultProps = {
  query: {}
};
```

There's a third option too - you've said that `global_props` might have a `query` prop and it might not; if you can guarantee that `global_props` **will** have the `query` property anytime that `<OtherPage />` is called, you could put a guard around that route -

```
{global_props.query && (
  <Route path="/other" element={<OtherPage {...global_props} />} />
)}
```

[Here's a code-sandbox you can play with](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-cartwright-xvyrg?file=/src/App.js) that might help. If you comment out the `query` property from both `defaultProps` and `global_props` then you receive an error; adding either one of them back in will remove the error.

To answer your actual question as to why you're getting this error even though the component isn't loaded: `prop-types` is just a bunch of validators that check your code when it loads. Think of it more like a compiler warning rather than a runtime warning.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @gerrod about the exact prop.

Comment: I've updated the example to better illustrate how it actually is. The global_props might get or might not get the query prop depend on the external factors. Would you please explain why it is still failing? What's going on under the hood? Thanks, mate

Comment: Thank you for the update, @gerrod. But the actual question is WHY is the validation happening in a component that is not even loaded?

Comment: Yep - the very last paragraph of my answer tells you that - `prop-types` is checking over your code when it gets loaded into the browser, not when the code executes.